# angular2 extend service with argument in constructor

Tags: angular, types, angular2-services

I have some problems in understanding how to extend correctly a service in angular2, maybe because I don't understand well how to extend a class in typescript.

## SuperClass

```
@Injectable()
export class CallService{
    constructor(private errror:string){
        this.errMsg=errror;
    }
    private _errMsg:string;
    set errMsg(arg0:string){
        this._errMsg=arg0;
    }
    get errMsg():string{
        return this._errMsg;
    }
}
```

## SubClass

```
@Injectable()
export class DownloadService extends CallService{
    constructor(private error:string,private http:Http){
        super(error)
    }
}
```

## App.Component

```
@Component({
selector:'my-app',
    templateUrl:'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls:['app/app.component.css'],
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,WaitComponent],
    providers:[DownloadService,SwitcherService,CallService,WaitService]
})
export class AppComponent{
    title:'App'
    constructor(
        private areadownloadservice:AreaDownloadService,
        private waitService:WaitService,
        private switcherservice:SwitcherService,
        private callService:CallService){}
    )
}
```

What I want to do is to extend some classes with CallService so that all class that make a calls will have a errMsg string property to set or get, but I get this exception:

> No provider for String!

What did I missed?

Comment: The problem is not a subclass. `string` type annotation in constructor makes the injector to look for `string` provider, and there is none, and there is also no provider defined for `error` in the component.

Comment: ok, and what's the right way to extend a service in the way that I write above?

Comment: What do you want Angular DI to pass in to the `error` parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either

- remove the `error` parameter
- make the `error` parameter optional

```ts
export class CallService{
    constructor(@Optional() private errror:string){

...

export class DownloadService extends CallService{
    constructor(@Optional() private error:string,private http:Http){
```

- or tell DI what it should pass

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, {provide: 'someToken', useValue: 'someStringValue'}])
```

```ts
export class CallService{
    constructor(@Inject('someToken') private errror:string){

...

export class DownloadService extends CallService{
    constructor(@Inject('someToken') private error:string,private http:Http){
```

You can also use an [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html) instead of the string key ('someToken').
See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 2):

At this line of code `constructor(private error:string,private http:Http){` you are telling the constructor to actually prepare for the `Http` and `string` services, but you do not have such a `string` Service declared anywhere.

Comment: it is a good answer too, it explain the error really well, but Gunter written a more complete solution